# $mysqli->error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Need help!!

I got this error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?, a.ip_description = ? WHERE b.id_ip_address = a.id_ip_address AND b.id_server =' at line 1

Here are my code

```
session_start();

include ('../connect.php');
$member_id = $_SESSION["id"];

$url = $_POST["url"]; //varchar
$list_ip_address = $_POST["list_ip_address"]; //int
$ip_description = $_POST["ip_description"]; //varchar
$dns_list = $_POST["dns_list"]; //int

$sql = "UPDATE virtual_server SET id_ip_address = ?, url = ? WHERE id_server = $member_id";
//This part right here is fine
$stsql = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stsql->bind_param('is', $list_ip_address, $url);

if ($stsql->execute()) {
    $ip = "UPDATE list_ip_address a, virtual_server b SET a.id_dns = ?, a.ip_description = ? 
            WHERE b.id_ip_address = a.id_ip_address AND b.id_server = $member_id";
    $stip = $mysqli->prepare($ip);
    $stip->bind_param('is', $dns_list, $ip_description);
```

Comment: Can you give us some example input for those variables?  We have no idea what data type they are, or what data type SQL expects.  This error might be due to mismatched data types between what SQL expects and what you're providing.

Comment: Why not parameterize `$member_id`? Is `id_ip_address` an integer?

Comment: Where is your `$mysqli->prepare($ip);`? Is it possible you are doing `$mysqli->query($ip);` by mistake?

Comment: My system was just fine before this @chris85 but i want to improve it a bit more..let me try first.
**Edit :**
Nope, still display same error

Comment: There, i add my code some more @Sean . Sorry for my mistake, i didn't put it ealier on